# two microservices linked with Rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq

I have two microservices.  One is connected to the mongodb database and the other to postgresql.  I need to transfer information from the second microservice to the first and vice versa, for this I used rabbimq, is it possible to use rabbitmq for such purposes or not? (Everything works for me, I'm only interested in whether I used rabbitmq correctly or not)

Comment: How do you use it? What scenario it is

Comment: @zolty13, Im writing a bookstore. One microservice responsible for registration and other for books. When a person want to buy a book with the help of rabbitmq I transfer the amount of money and id of user to book microservice, in book microservice I have a method with RabbitListener annotation that get the information and then I work with user's info in book store. After that Im updating a purse of a user after buying a book and transfer back updated purse to registration microservice and then database table of user updating with a new amount of money after buying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways to communicate/transfer data.

1)Expose HTTP endpoint(/GET in your case), so any other microservice can get the information over HTTP.

2)As you are already implemented, publish the event with data, and other ms will listen to the event and sync with data.

As you mentioned in a comment, for your requirement, async communication is best option.